# What does it precisely mean that the suffix -ship "denotes a state of being"?

Tags: suffixes

> Over two decades, she enjoyed a memorable and mystifying ***acquaintanceship*** with Ramirez.

Does it precisely mean that the suffix *-ship* "[denotes a state of being](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ship#section_1)"?

After having read that definition, I conclude that *fellowship* is the state of being *fellow*, but, I wonder, is not "fellow" already a state of being? How can a person be a *fellow* without having that state?

And, in the sentence above (The New York Times), why does the journalist use "acquaintanceship" rather than "acquaintance"—perhaps the fact that the state perdured "over two decades"?  What does -ship add to "acquaintance"?

Comment: I think its just journalistic license. "acquaintance" by itself is OK. http://grammarist.com/usage/acquaintanceship/ . http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acquaintanceship says "uncountable" but that would not apply to this example. Maybe "...mystifying acquaintanceship with others."

Comment: @Carlo_R. *Fellowship* is only *the state of being [a] fellow* when *fellow* has its specialised academic sense (but in such contexts the extension in meaning is actually more akin to *professorship*). In other contexts, *fellowship* is much more like *friendship* or *companionship* - it identifies the nature of a ***relationship***.

Answer (score 1):

*Acquaintance* means "a person that you know but who is not a close friend" or "slight friendship"; *acquaintanceship* means "a slight friendship with somebody or knowledge of something."

I take you can use *acquaintance* instead of *acquaintanceship* at least in sentences like the following one.

> He hoped their acquaintance would develop further.

Generally speaking *-ship* can mean many things, including "the state of quality of" (e.g. *friendship*), "the status or office of (e.g. *citizenship*, *professorship*).

Comment: kiam, I know friendship means "amicizia", but I cannot think to an Italian word for "professorship" except "professorato", which don't seem a word. Please, explain.

Comment: _Professorship_ can be both _professorato_ or _cattedra universitaria_.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: In general, *xxxx-ship* denotes *the state or condition of being xxxx*, but each individual term thus formed will have its own specific meaning. For example, *craftsmanship* doesn't usually mean *the state of being a craftsman* - it's usually applied to *things which have been **created by** a craftsman*. And *professorship* is *the office of a professor* in the same way *presidency* is *the office of being president*. It just so happens that for *acquaintaince* we often use the bare root word where it's *possible* to use the derived term *acquaintanceship* (it's a synonym).